# Using Modal in Blazor

Tags: modal-dialog, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a modal that have two buttons "Delete and Cancel".

When i click on the Delete-button this code below will execute.

```
<BSModal @ref="ConfDelete">
            <BSModalHeader OnClick="@(() => ConfDelete.Hide())">Uppdragsnummer:@report.AssignmentNumber</BSModalHeader>
            <BSModalBody><p>Vill du verkligen radera??</p></BSModalBody>
            <BSModalFooter>
                <BSButton Color="Color.Secondary" @onclick="@(() => Cancel())">Ångra</BSButton>
                <BSButton Color="Color.Danger" @onclick="@(() => DeleteReport())">Tabort</BSButton>
            </BSModalFooter>
        </BSModal>

@code {
    BSModal ConfDelete;
public void DeleteReport()
    {
        imanager.Delete(report);
        navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
}
```

When i come back to the page where all the
reports are listed. And click on a other report and go there.

I can not scroll on that page. But, if i refresh the site "manually" i can scroll.
How can i solve this in the code?
What have i missed?

Comment: Hi Anders. This isn't enough information. Nobody can help you with only the information in the question. Add more, otherwise someone will close it.

Comment: Thanks @PeterMorris. I hope that the code i have added can help peolpe to understand it better.

Comment: It sounds like the backdrop is not being properly cleared based on the behavior you have described where you can't scroll, but I would think you wouldn't be able to click on anything either. I'm not familiar with BSModal, but it looks like some kind of 3rd party library. Have you opened an issue on the GitHub project?

Comment: @Lex, I have not done that. But i will now :) . Thanks for that point!